# Implementing tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath in storyboard

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

How would you implement tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath in storyboard. I have already created a view controller that creates the table. I don't know what to do in the storyboard to get the view to transition when clicking each cell in the table.

This is what I originally had programmatically inside that method:

```
Show *show = [self.shows objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
ShowContentItem *showItem = show.showContentItems[indexPath.row];

if ([showItem.contentType isEqualToString:@"Headline_Section"]) {
    HeadlinesViewController *headlinesVC = [[HeadlinesViewController alloc] init];
    headlinesVC.shows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:show, nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:headlinesVC animated:YES];
} else {
    NSInteger contentIndex = [self.storyPostContent indexOfObject:showItem];
    NSRange rangeForView = NSMakeRange(contentIndex, [self.storyPostContent count] - contentIndex );

    ShowContentViewController *showContentVC = [[ShowContentViewController alloc] init];
    showContentVC.contentList = [self.storyPostContent subarrayWithRange: rangeForView];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: showContentVC animated:YES];
}
```

How would I specifically alter the code above to work with storyboard?

Comment: In your storyboard, did you configure your table to be statically, or dynamically populated?

Comment: Dynamically populated.

Comment: Have you configured a class to conform to the [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol, and linked the table's delegate property to this class?

Comment: Yep I have that done.

Answer (score 1):

You control drag from your prototype cell to your destination controller. Then in `prepareForSegue` you do something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegue"]) {
        yourViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationController.someVariable = yourTable.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I need to add a segue in the storyboard? If so, to what?

Comment: From the prototype cell to the destination view controller.

Comment: Do I still need to have didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: No you don't if you are using segues.